# ButterKnife: Not found. Trying superclass android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, butterknife, null-pointer

I am trying to bind TextView using **`Butterknife`** I have main activity and layout consist TextView with id tv_app_name. Which I follow from [documentation](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@BindView(R.id.tv_app_name)
TextView tvAppName;

@BindString(R.string.app_name)
String appName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    ButterKnife.setDebug(true);

    tvAppName.setText(appName);


 }
}
```

I encounter with a problem that the **`tvAppName`** is not initialized and showing `nullPointerException`. And I added **`ButterKnife.setDebug(true);`** As suggested in some answers in StackOverflow And I found in log showing **`ButterKnife: Not found. Trying superclass android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`**.

While I searching for solution to this issue. some had said add dependency `butterknife-compiler`, but I have already added like:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //butterknife
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    apk 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
}
```

what is the problem bihinde:

**ButterKnife: Not found. Trying superclass android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity**
and how do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in your dependencies. The line in your build.gradle file

> **apk** 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'

should be

> **apt** 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'

You also need to add

> classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'

to your Project level build.gradle file -- See https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife#download for more information.